# Problema con metodo POST ajax con jqery y php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

Qué tal, estoy comenzando con ajax y por más que he buscado no encuentro el error, quiero enviar por metodo post una imagen pero no resulta, me podrían ayudar? dejo el código, desde ya gracias.

Creo que el error está en la parte de ajax, pero no me resulta.

> index.html

```
   <!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/mijs.js"></script>
        <title>inicio</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4"> </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <form id="frm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                         <div class="form-group">
                             <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" id="nombre" name="nombre">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="btn btn-primary" for="my-file-selector">
                                <input id="my-file-selector" type="file" style="display:none" name="img"
                                onchange="$('#upload-file-info').html(this.files[0].name)">
                                Subir archivo
                            </label>
                            <span class='label label-info' id="upload-file-info"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input id="guardar" type="submit" value="ENVIAR" class="btn btn-primary">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="resp" class="col-sm-4">Hola </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
               $("#guardar").click(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'mandar.php',
                        type:'POST',
                        data:$('#frm').serialize()
                        ,success:function(){
                            alert('OK');
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

> mandar.php

```
<?php
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $img = $_FILES['img']['name'];
    $ruta = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
    $destino = "fotos/".$img;
    if($_FILES['img']['size'] > 500000){
        echo 'El archivo es muy grande!!';
        die('sube un archivo más pequeño');
    }
    copy($ruta, $destino);
    include './db_const.php';

    $con = new mysqli($host, $username, $passwd, $dbname);
    if(!$con){
        echo 'ERROR DE CONEXION',$con->connect_errno;
        die('ERROR');
    }
    $qy = "insert into alumnos (nombre,imagen) values('{$nombre}','{$destino}');";
    if($con->query($qy)){
        echo 'Todo bien';
    }
    else{
        echo 'ERROR';
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que pasa en tu caso es que se esta enviando el formulario por método convencional mas no por ajax, por que ? por que tu botón es de tipo submit, cambialo a tipo button y vuelve a probar

Comment: valla, entre tantas modificaciones eso resolvía ese problema, ahora el problema es que solo se guarda 'fotos/ ' en la base de datos, no se guarda la copia en el servidor ni el nombre del archivo la BD pero bueno ya es un avance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifica tu script de la siguiente manera

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#guardar").submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       let formData = new FormData(this);
       $.ajax({
         url:'mandar.php',
         type:'POST',
         data: formData,,
         async: false,
         success:function(){
           alert('OK');
         }
       });
    });
 });
</script>
```

Y en tu HTML cambia esto:

```
<input id="guardar" type="submit" value="ENVIAR" class="btn btn-primary">
```

Por esto:

```
<button id="guardar" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
```

Y en tu etiqueta `<form>` del HTML añade el atributo `method="post"`

El objeto [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData) te permiten enviar datos a través de AJAX/XMLHttpRequest, es principalmente usado para el envío de datos del formulario y además te permite enviar archivos. Puedes checar [más información aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData).

Comment: gracias por la info y la ayuda, resuelve ese problema sin embargo ahora el problema es que solo guarda 'fotos/ ' en la base de datos, no se guarda la copia en el servidor ni el nombre del archivo la BD. Pero checaré esos enlaces, se ven que son de mucha utilidad.

Comment: Ese problema que tienes en la base de datos tiene que ver con la parte del back y no del front. Podrías finalizar está pregunta y crear una nueva acorde a tu nuevo problema. Así se puede clarificar todo con mayor facilidad.

Comment: perfecto gracias por las respuestas.