# index indefinido al recibir paremetros de ajax en php

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo un documento html con un formulario, al enviarlo ejecuta esta función

```
function send(){
        var f_name = document.contact_form.f_name.value;
        var l_name = document.contact_form.l_name.value;
        var email = document.contact_form.email.value;
        var msj = document.contact_form.msj.value;
        if(f_name!='' && l_name!='' && email!='' && msj!='' ){
          $.ajax({
            url : 'BackEnd/send_message.php?name='+f_name+l_name+'&email='+email+'&msj='+msj,
            type : 'post',
            success: function(res){
              if(res){
                show('Message send :)');
              }else{
                show('MISTAKE in server');
              }
            },error:function(){
                alert('MISTAKE in server2');
              }
          });
          return;
        }
        else{
          show('Incomplete form');
          return false;
        }
      }
```

El archivo al que se esta enviando tiene esto:

```
$name = $_REQUEST['name']; 
$from = $_REQUEST['email'];
$msj = $_REQUEST['msj'];

$to = 'example@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Message to CONTACT';
$header = 'From: '.$from;

echo mail($to, $subject, $name.$msj, $header);
```

Pero sale el error de que la variable `name` esta indefinida

```
Notice: Undefined index: name in /home/denso/LAMMP/dashboard/WWW/Administradores/BackEnd/send_message.php on line 2
```

Ya intente varias cosas pero aun así sale el error

Comment: Intenta cambiar el method POST por GET en tu ajax.

Comment: sigue sin funcionar

Comment: De hecho porque tienes declarado en type POST??, en type no debe ir POST, debe ir es el tipo de respuesta que deseas por parte del servidor, si deseas especificar un metodo debes especificar el atributo method como POST o GET en ajax, en tu caso tendria que ser GET.

Comment: Hay problemas de formato en el como haces tu peticion ajax, te recomiendo leer la documentacion: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problema con metodo POST ajax con jqery y php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109357/problema-con-metodo-post-ajax-con-jqery-y-php)

Answer (score 0):

Amigo intenta con esto

```
function send(){
  var f_name = document.contact_form.f_name.value;
  var l_name = document.contact_form.l_name.value;
  var email = document.contact_form.email.value;
  var msj = document.contact_form.msj.value;
  if(f_name!='' && l_name!='' && email!='' && msj!='' ){
    $.ajax({
      url : 'BackEnd/send_message.php'
      method: 'GET',
      data: {
        "name": f_name + " " + l_name,
        "email": email,
        "msj": msj
      },
      success: function(res){
        if(res){
          alert('Message send :)');
        }else{
          alert('MISTAKE in server');
        }
      },error:function(){
          alert('MISTAKE in server2');
        }
    });
    return;
  }
  else{
    alert('Incomplete form');
    return false;
  }
}
```

Y del lado del servidor

```
$name = isset($_GET['name'])?$_GET['name']:NULL;
$from = isset($_GET['email'])?$_GET['email']:NULL;
$msj = isset($_GET['msj'])?$_GET['msj']:NULL;

$to = 'example@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Message to CONTACT';
$header = 'From: '.$from;
```

Establece que si no existe cualquier dato le asignara NULL